# RVM and Ruby version not working as expected

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I want to install the compass [html5 boilerplate](https://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5-boilerplate) gem.  When I try to install it I get the following error.

```
$ sudo gem install html5-boilerplate
ERROR:  Error installing html5-boilerplate:
compass-h5bp requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.
```

Then when I check my ruby version it says:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

But I used RVM before so I thought I could just change version but when I check it says I'm using ruby-2.2.0 already.

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I think I must be missing something obhvious, it's been a while since I've worked with Ruby and RVM.

**Update 1**

I ran the below commands as suggested by @tadman and it does seem the wrong path is being used.

```
~:$ cd ~/.rvm/bin
bin:$ ls
ruby-rvm-env  rvm  rvm-auto-ruby  rvm-exec  rvm-prompt  rvm-shebang-ruby  rvm-shell  rvm-smile  rvmsudo
bin:$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

### UPDATE 2

After correcting the path in my `.bash_profile` the ruby version seems correct but I'm still getting the same error when trying to install the html5-boilerplate gem??

```
$ sudo gem install html5-boilerplate
ERROR:  Error installing html5-boilerplate:
    compass-h5bp requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ compass -v
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2015 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass
```

Also i have the compass gem installed on both Ruby 1.9.1 and RVM's ruby 2.2.0.  Could this have something to do with it?

```
$ pwd
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-1.0.3
$ cd /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3
$ pwd
/home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3
```

Is there a way to check which ruby version compass is using?

Answer (score 1):

Having RVM and having RVM installed correctly are two different things. The most common cause of a mismatch like this is that your system Ruby has priority in your `PATH`.

In a POSIX shell, `which ruby` will tell you which one is getting executed. It is probably the wrong one.

RVM does its magic by manipulating which Ruby shows up in the RVM bin path, often `~/.rvm/bin` or something similar. To get it to work correctly you'll need to ensure that path is first in your `$PATH`.

You may want to try reinstalling the RVM stub, or check that it's correctly loaded into your environment.

Comment: It does seem to be using the wrong path.  See my update in the question. How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure `rvm.sh` is properly imported into your environment. It may be missing or skipped for some reason. Normally you'll see `source rvm.sh` somewhere in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or something equivalent.

Comment: thanks.  That seemed to fix rvm, the correct ruby version is now showing but I still get the same error when I try to install html5-boilerplate gem?  I updated my question again.

Comment: Have you tried not using `sudo` to install the Gem? Using `sudo` installs the gem to the ruby version for the super user, or root user on a system. This is not necessary with RVM. Just `gem install html5-boilerplate` should work.